# Prohibit the sending of the form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On the [page](http://plnkr.co/edit/LViaEDTlZvboSaO8EP9w?p=preview) after clicking "submit" form is submitted. But I forbade controller ctrlPersonalData form submission (return false)

Please help me cancel the sending of the form after clicking "submit"

Comment: If it is a secure form, you may want to look at a PHP solution as some browser extensions allow HTML and JavaScript editing

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple HTML trick but should work for you:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
...
</form>
```

> Please take this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: I would like to cancel the sending of the form is in the controller and not in the attribute

I use angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `action="#"` attribute from the form. Also in AngularJS you dont make a form post you make ajax calls with model data.